Show that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, 1)$
I want to use the following criterion:

Let $f \colon A \to \mathbb R$ be a function. If there are sequences $x_n, y_n$ in $A$ such that $|x_n - y_n| \to 0$, and $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \to a \neq 0 $,  as $n \to \infty$, then $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $A$.

Let $x_n=\frac{1}{2n}, y_n=\frac{1}{3n}$, then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2n}=0=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y_n$$
hence $|x_n - y_n| \to 0$, as $n \to \infty$.
Now since $f(x_n) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2n}} = 2n$ and  $f(y_n) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{3n}} = 3n$
EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, it's better to do the following $$|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| = |2n - 3n| = |-n| = n > 0 \space \forall n \in \mathbb N$$ which proves the claim.
we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2n=+\infty=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}3n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)$$
and thus $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \to \infty \neq 0$, which means $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, 1)$.
I guess I'm essentially asking if the $a$ in the quoted criterion above can be $\pm \infty$, i.e. is $a \in \mathbb R \cup \{ - \infty, +\infty \}$.

If $(|f (x_n) - f (y_n)|)_n$ does not converge (when $(|x_n - y_n|)_n \to 0$), then you've surely shown that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

I prefer not writing the line $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\cdots$, just writing $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=n$ is better because both limits diverge to infinity does not imply their absolute difference diverge to infinity (tho it is in this case)

Also, you have a typo: $f$ is continuous on $(0, 1)$, just not uniformly so.

You just need to show that there is some $a>0$ such that $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \ge a$ for infinitely many $n$.

Another approach is to note that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on a bounded interval, then $f$ must be bounded (why?).

@copper.hat to answer your "why?": first of all, that'd be helpful because of the contraposition and the fact that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not bounded. As why the statement itself is true: since $f$ is unbounded $f(x) \to \infty$ for some $x$. So for a given small $\varepsilon$ centered around $f(x)$, $$|\underbrace{f^{-1}(x+\varepsilon)}{=x_1}-\underbrace{f^{-1}(x-\varepsilon)}{=x_2}| \to 0 \implies |x_1 - x_2| \to 0, f(x) \to \infty $$ so this means that a single $\delta$ won't be able to be a bound for all $|x_1 - x_2|$, since we can find $x_1, x_2$ that are arbitrarily close to each other.thx!

@AnneBauval thanks and thanks for the additional exercise you keep giving!

@copper.hat so I could've simply done the following: $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| = |2n - 3n| = |-n| = n > 0 \space \forall n \in \mathbb N$ of which there are infinitely many ?

@powerline Yes, but make sure you understand why.

Note that the limit $a$ is necessarily $\ge0$, hence $\ne-\infty$. Apart from this, the answer to your question is YES, since the usual sequential criterion (for metric spaces) is:

$f:(X,d)\to(Y,\delta)$ is not uniformly continuous iff$$\exists\epsilon>0\quad\exists(x_n)_n,(y_n)_n\in X^{\Bbb N}\quad d(x_n,y_n)\to0\text{ and }\delta(f(x_n),f(y_n))\ge\epsilon,$$

and if $\delta(f(x_n),f(y_n))\to a>0$ then, for every $n$ large enough, $\delta(f(x_n),f(y_n))\ge a/2$ if $a$ is finite, and $\ge1$ (for instance) if $a=\infty$.
Your criterion is even not only sufficient, but still necessary, because if $\delta(f(x_n),f(y_n))\ge\epsilon$,
then the sequence $a_n:=\delta(f(x_n),f(y_n))$ has a subsequence $a_{n_k}\to a\in[\epsilon,\infty]$.

$a=\pm \infty$ does complete the proof, yes. If you're unsure, you could use $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

I was about to give this answer.
